# Issue with YAML Linter in MegaLinter - Unable to Detect Files in Git Repository

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, cicd, lint

I am currently using the MegaLinter GitHub Action in my CI workflow to lint various file types, including YAML files. The YAML linter seems to be initiated correctly as part of the MegaLinter setup, but I'm encountering an issue where it is unable to detect files in the Git repository. The MegaLinter output indicates that it cannot list git ignored files and, consequently, keeps zero files.

Here is a snippet of the relevant part in my GitHub Action workflow:

```yaml
 action.yml
 name: Run CI Light Linters
 on:
  push:
   branches:
    - main

 jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run CI Light Linters
        id: Mega-Linters
        if: ${{ inputs.ENABLE_LINTERS == '' }}
        uses: oxsecurity/megalinter/flavors/ci_light@fda6ac3a38be0e969820709ac16e442464e5a035
        with:
         # other configuration options...
         ENABLE_LINTERS: "YAML_PRETTIER"
        env:
         VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: true
         continue-on-error: true
```

**MegaLinter Output**

Here is the relevant output from MegaLinter:

```
> MegaLinter now collects the files to analyse (expand for details)
Listing all files in directory [/github/workspace], then filter with:
> 
> - File extensions: .yaml, .yml   Unable to list git ignored files (/github/workspace)   Kept [0] files on [0] found files
> 
> +----MATCHING LINTERS-+----------+----------------+------------+ | Descriptor | Linter | Criteria | Matching files | Format/Fix |
> +------------+--------+----------+----------------+------------+
> 
> +----SUMMARY-+--------+------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+ | Descriptor | Linter | Mode | Files | Fixed | Errors | Elapsed time |
> +------------+--------+------+-------+-------+--------+--------------+
> 
> Unable to find git repository to list updated files [Updated Sources
> Reporter] No source file has been formatted or fixed ✅ Successfully
> linted all files without errors
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like you can set [`IGNORE_GITIGNORED_FILES`](https://github.com/oxsecurity/megalinter?tab=readme-ov-file#common-variables) to `false` to alter this default behavior.

Comment: Is that a valid flavor?  Try `...flavors/ci_light@latest` instead.

Comment: Try removing your `if` condition to make sure it's not blocking the step.

Comment: You can also try dropping your `with` and your `env` and use config files for MegaLinter (.mega-linter.yml) and yamllint (.yamllint.yml) instead.